# Mac is freezing. How to find the problem?

Tags: macos, performance

I have Macbook Pro Retina (Late 2013) with installed El capitan.

Sometimes OSX just freezing and I can do nothing, but to reboot (by holding power button for a few seconds). All apps are continue running, for example media player or torrent client. But keyboard or trackpad doesn't respond.

I read lots of manuals, I tried reset different settings, clear user's cache. I even tried reinstall OSX (without formatting the drive). It's not helping.

I don't have much experience with OSX, so I don't know where to look for a problem. Any thoughts what should I do?

Comment: I don't have any special software installed. Just regular stuff, like Chrome and Skype. Plus some apps for webdev - Jetbrains software, plus homebrew with php/ruby, etc. I checked the list of software, and don't see anything unusual. I also can't find the pattern here, because this problem can happens any time, when different apps are launched

Comment: Did you check this? https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Apple Diagnostics to check for hardware issues:
Restart your computer, then hold down the D key while the Mac restarts.

Check Apple knowledge base on this subject - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21879

If you get an error-code, check this page for how to follow it up:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203747

Comment: yes, I did it, it doesn't shows anything

Comment: hm, I run it second time and I got this error: `PPT004
The battery requires service. The battery is not functioning normally, though you may not notice a change in its behavior or the amount of charge it holds. You can continue to use your battery before its checked without harming your computer.`

Comment: It seems that your macbook is somewhat unstable. Check this link for suggestions on what to do for this error-code:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203747

Comment: Diagnostic tool offered to bring my Mac to Apple Care, but I'm away now, will do it next week. It said I have coverage for it. But can this battery issue, cause freezes?

Comment: I do not know much about power-handling in on portable components, but I would guess that if a component get irregular voltage input, it may cause the system to freeze. Some components may be more tolerant than others.

Comment: yeah, but all apps are still working, for example when I watch movie and osx freezes, I can continue to watch the movie, but I can't interact with laptop anyhow. That's why it looks weird to me. Anyway, I will visit Apple Store as soon as I'll get a chance. Thanks